# Make a Linux OS

Tags: linux, assembly, operating-system, kernel

I am making a smart home device and I need to make my own linux os from the ground up including the GUI and some assembly code I know will be necessary. What programming languages will I need to learn? What software will I need? Where do I start? Will I have to make my own kernel?

Comment: This question is a bit broad. I suppose the best response I have is why do you need a custom Linux distro? There are tons of good distros that run on a wide range of processorse

Comment: Did you install Linux on your laptop to become familiar with it? Did you compile a few software under Linux? Look at source distributions like [gentoo](http://gentoo.org/) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: Yes I know how to use Linux. I can do java and am willing to learn new programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not programmer and have not any such skills so run and dont look behind and save yourself but if not look at this: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: I am a programmer, I like that "run and don't look behind". Thank you for your input.